# UIButton Title In .xib Overriding Programmatic Title Change

Tags: ios

I am writing an app which loads a view (designed in a .xib) with multiple buttons. When loading the view I set the buttons titles programmatically. I then add the view as a subview. For a fleeting second I see the programatically set titles appear and then they change to the prototype titles in the .xib.

Here is the code:

```
self.cellPhoneButton.titleLabel.text = person.cellPhone;
self.homePhoneButton.titleLabel.text = person.homePhone;

// Do other stuff with the view

[self.peopleView addSubview:self.personView];
```

Why do the titles of the buttons revert back to their default content, and why is this not happening to the other components of the page (Labels, Navigation Bar Title, etc.)?

**EDIT:**

I also tried this code without success:

```
[self.cellPhoneButton setTitle:person.cellPhone forState:UIControlStateNormal|UIControlStateSelected];
[self.homePhoneButton setTitle:person.homePhone forState:UIControlStateNormal|UIControlStateSelected];

// Do other stuff with the view

[self.peopleView addSubview:self.personView];
```

Comment: Which method did you put this code in?

Comment: @BlackRider This code is in a method which is called by the method `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: After setting the button titles, you then add *which* view as a subview?

Comment: @LyndseyScott I add `self.personView` as a subview to `self.peopleView` which is a subview of `self.view`.

Comment: have you tried `[self.homePhoneButton setTitle: forState:]` method?

Comment: @Chancy Which states should I set it for if I just want the text to remain the same?

Comment: try `UIControlStateNormal`

Comment: @Chancy Still the same. I updated the question to include the code I tried.

Comment: how you set the state? only `UIControlStateNormal`? i see you use | to combine two. Normal is enough.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43385/discussion-between-chancy-and-cabellicar123)

Comment: Even though it's apparently not the solution to your problem, you definitely need to do what Clancy mentioned with setTitle:ForState:…  Are the buttons part of the superview's .xib or are they part of the personView .xib?  Because from what it sounds like, you're adding the buttons to a subview, but their declaration is in the superview.  I could be misunderstanding though...

Comment: @LyndseyScott Setting the title for only the state `UIControlStateNormal` was successful. However, just fyi:
My .xib contains 4 views. The buttons are located inside the view linked as the property `personView` in the `viewController`. The buttons are also linked as properties in the `viewController`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `[self.homePhoneButton setTitle: forState:];` method to set the `UIButton`'s title. and the state in your case should be `UIControlStateNormal` which means control state will apply to all the states if you don't specify the others explicitly. If you combine the Normal with others, then Normal will be overidded.